# Mule ESB - http inbound-endpoint user authentication

Tags: mule, esb

How to setup user authentication (verification of username and password) fro Mule ESB http inbound-endpoint?

This http inbound-endpoint will be used for REST service.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
<spring:beans>
   <security:authentication-manager alias="MyManager">
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service id="UserService">
                <security:user name="someusername" password="somepassword" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
   </security:authentication-manager> 
</spring:beans>

<spring-security:security-manager>
    <spring-security:delegate-security-provider delegate-ref="MyManager" name="InMemory"/>
</spring-security:security-manager>

<flow name="main">
    <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/secured">
        <spring-security:http-security-filter realm="mule-realm" securityProviders="InMemory"/>
    </http:inbound-endpoint>
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Mule can be configured with **Spring security** to provide basic authentication with **username** and **password**. The spring security can also be configured to provide **role** based support where multiple users involve .
Some example you can refer here to get more ideas on it :- http://confluex.com/blog/http-inbound-endpoint-basic-authentication/
and
http://www.javaroots.com/2013/06/how-to-secure-rest-services-in-mule-3.html
also
https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Configuring+the+Spring+Security+Manager